# How to decrease RAM programmatically in Hazelcast configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, hazelcast

I have Ubuntu Server (16 GB RAM). 40 microservices including **hazelcast**. Every services include IMap in it. Without hazelcast there is no problem.

I can run all my jar in server easily. But after including hazelcast i can only run max 20 services apprx. My every jar drunk `400/500 mb ram`. I tested `Xms:128` and `Xmx:256` no effect. I found that Hazelcast drinks my RAM.

Comment: Can you provide more detail ? How specifically do you set `Xmx` ? How specifically do you determine the RAM use ? Newer versions of Hazelcast log this, so that would be ideal, turn on `hazelcast.diagnostics.enabled`

Comment: Set Xmx: java  -Xms128m -Xmx256m -jar xmies_protokol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Can you add `-Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true` and `-Dhazelcast.health.monitoring.level=NOISY` just before `-jar` and post the output from the `HealthMonitor` please.

Comment: "How specifically do you determine the RAM use ?" i didn't get what you mean ?

Comment: Ok. I will be back after test

Comment: HealthMonitor  - ? where is it ?

Comment: The `Xmx` limits heap. It looks correctly specified, the Hazelcast diagnostic will prove it. The health monitor information from Hazelcast comes out to the system out console. Heap is not the only part of the process that uses RAM, it's just the most likely place.

Comment: -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true and -Dhazelcast.health.monitoring.level=NOISY                                          
R_E_S_U_L_T : https://justpaste.it/5hdsv

Comment: `Metric[memory.maxHeap=250609664]`. You get the max heap you asked for.  When you say "_My every jar drunk 400/500 mb ram_" how do you measure this ?

Comment: You might want to try adding `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary`. See [section 2.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html#BABIIIAC). It's unlikely to be a leak, but `jcmd` will show you how much is used other than the heap.

Comment: Hmm if it is no fault of hazelcast, what is the problem ? Because of, after using hazelcast these problem occured........

Comment: @Neil Stevensonthanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast is expected to use some memory space, more so when you store any data as the data gets stored in the same memory space. However, it would be to enable diagnostics with NOISY as Neil mentioned, so that you can investigate the use of memory and with the help of a heap dump, a possible memory leak.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you exactly. You say that heap dump will help me to find hazelcast dringing RAM or not or i can find drunken RAM inside heap ?

Answer (score 0):

The example posted in the comments has `Xmx` correctly set. Heap size can't go above 256 and in fact only reaches half that.

```
28-07-2019 14:29:51 1564309791127 Metric[memory.maxHeap=254279680]
28-07-2019 14:29:51 1564309791127 Metric[memory.usedHeap=125628696]
```

Please clarify how you think 400Mb-500Mb is being used. If heap is capped at 256Mb you need to examine the rest of the process, using `jcmd` or similar.

You also have

```
28-07-2019 14:29:51 1564309791127 Metric[thread.peakThreadCount=80]
```

which might explain much of the non-heap usage. They might be using a 1Mb each.